# Overriding Last-Modified header in http.FileServer

Tags: go, http-headers, last-modified

I'm trying to override the `Last-Modified`-header set by `http.FileServer`, but it reverts to the `Last-Modified`-time of the file I'm trying to serve:

```
var myTime time.Time

func main() {
     myTime = time.Now()         

     fs := http.StripPrefix("/folder/", SetCacheHeader(http.FileServer(http.Dir("/folder/"))))
     http.Handle("/folder/", fs)
     http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

My `SetCacheHeader`-handler:

```
func SetCacheHeader(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Last-Modified", myTime.Format(http.TimeFormat))
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The handler returned by [`http.FileServer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) unconditionally sets the `"Last-Modified"` header in the `http.serveFile()` and `http.serveContent()` unexported functions:

```
func serveFile(w ResponseWriter, r *Request, fs FileSystem,
    name string, redirect bool) {

    // ...
    f, err := fs.Open(name)
    // ...
    d, err := f.Stat()
    // ...

    // serveContent will check modification time
    sizeFunc := func() (int64, error) { return d.Size(), nil }
    serveContent(w, r, d.Name(), d.ModTime(), sizeFunc, f)
}

func serveContent(w ResponseWriter, r *Request, name string, modtime time.Time,
    sizeFunc func() (int64, error), content io.ReadSeeker) {
    setLastModified(w, modtime)
    // ...
}


func setLastModified(w ResponseWriter, modtime time.Time) {
    if !isZeroTime(modtime) {
        w.Header().Set("Last-Modified", modtime.UTC().Format(TimeFormat))
    }
}
```

So what you set prior to calling the file server handler will get overwritten. You can't really do anything about this.

If you need to serve the content of a file with custom last-modified time, you may use [`http.ServeContent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent):

```
func ServeContent(w ResponseWriter, req *Request, name string,
    modtime time.Time, content io.ReadSeeker)
```

Where you can pass the last-modified time to be used, but then of course you lose all the convenient features provided by `http.FileServer()`.

If you want to keep using `http.FileServer()`, another option would be to not use the [`http.Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir) type, but create your own [`http.FileSystem`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) implementation that you pass to `http.FileServer()`, in which you could report any last-modified timestamp you wish.

This would require you to implement the following interface:

```
type FileSystem interface {
        Open(name string) (File, error)
}
```

So you need a method which opens a file by its name, and returns a value which implements [`http.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#File), which is:

```
type File interface {
        io.Closer
        io.Reader
        io.Seeker
        Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error)
        Stat() (os.FileInfo, error)
}
```

And the value you return (that implements `http.File`) could have a `Stat() (os.FileInfo, error)` method implementation, whose [`os.FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) returned value contains the last-modified time of your choosing. Note that you should also implement the `Readdir()` method to return custom last-modified timestamps consistent with the timestamps returned by `Stat()`'s fileinfo. See related question how to do that: [Simples way to make a []byte into a "virtual" File object in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697277/simples-way-to-make-a-byte-into-a-virtual-file-object-in-golang/52697900#52697900)