# Simples way to make a []byte into a "virtual" File object in golang?

Tags: go, virtual-file

I know there are Go libraries that create entire filesystems like [VFS](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/godoc/vfs). But I only want to make a byte array into something that can fulfil the [File](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#File) interface.

Comment: Do you actually have to mock an entire file? I'm not sure how a slice of bytes would logically implement `Readdir` (other than `[]os.FileInfo{}, someErr`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no ready solution for this in the standard library, but it's not that hard to do it yourself.

What we need is this [`http.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#File) interface:

```
type File interface {
        io.Closer
        io.Reader
        io.Seeker
        Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error)
        Stat() (os.FileInfo, error)
}
```

Please note that we can utilize [`bytes.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader) to do the heavy task, as that alone implements [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) and [`io.Seeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Seeker). [`io.Closer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Closer) can be a noop, and `Readdir()` may return `nil, nil` as we're mocking a file not a directory, its `Readdir()` won't even be called.

The "hardest" part is to mock `Stat()` to return a value that implements [`os.FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo).

Here's a simple mocked `FileInfo`:

```
type myFileInfo struct {
    name string
    data []byte
}

func (mif myFileInfo) Name() string       { return mif.name }
func (mif myFileInfo) Size() int64        { return int64(len(mif.data)) }
func (mif myFileInfo) Mode() os.FileMode  { return 0444 }        // Read for all
func (mif myFileInfo) ModTime() time.Time { return time.Time{} } // Return anything
func (mif myFileInfo) IsDir() bool        { return false }
func (mif myFileInfo) Sys() interface{}   { return nil }
```

And with that we have everything to create our mocked `http.File`:

```
type MyFile struct {
    *bytes.Reader
    mif myFileInfo
}

func (mf *MyFile) Close() error { return nil } // Noop, nothing to do

func (mf *MyFile) Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
    return nil, nil // We are not a directory but a single file
}

func (mf *MyFile) Stat() (os.FileInfo, error) {
    return mf.mif, nil
}
```

Example using it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2RK40-pTRAH)):

```
data := []byte{0, 1, 2, 3}

mf := &MyFile{
    Reader: bytes.NewReader(data),
    mif: myFileInfo{
        name: "somename.txt",
        data: data,
    },
}

var f http.File = mf
_ = f
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough to mock this yourself.

```
type MockFile struct {
    data    []byte
    isOpen  bool
    offset  int64
}

type MockFileInfo struct {
    mockFile *MockFile
}
func (mfi *MockFileInfo) Name() string       { return "MockFile" }
func (mfi *MockFileInfo) Size() int64        { return len(mfi.data) }
func (mfi *MockFileInfo) Mode() os.FileMode  { return os.ModeIrregular }
func (mfi *MockFileInfo) ModTime() time.Time { return time.Now() }
func (mfi *MockFileInfo) IsDir() bool        { return false }
func (mfi *MockFileInfo) Sys() interface     { return nil }

func (mf *MockFile) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if mf.isOpen {
        n = copy(p, mf.data[mf.offset:])
        mf.offset += n
    } else {
        err = errors.New("Cannot read from closed MockFile")
    }
    return
}

func (mf *MockFile) Close() error {
    if !mf.isOpen {
        return errors.New("Cannot close an already closed MockFile")
    mf.isOpen = false
    return nil
}

func (mf *MockFile) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (ret int64, err error) {
    var relativeTo int64
    switch whence {
        case 0:
            relativeTo = 0
        case 1:
            relativeTo = mf.offset
        case 2:
            relativeTo = len(mf.data)
    }
    ret := relativeTo + offset
    if ret < 0 || ret > len(mf.data) {
        return -1, errors.New("New offset would fall outside of the MockFile")
    }
    mf.offset = ret
    return
}

func (mf *MockFile) Readdir(count int) ([]os.FileInfo, error) {
    if count <= 0 {
        return []os.FileInfo{}, nil
    }
    return []os.FileInfo{}, errors.New("MockFiles have no associated directory")
}

func (mf *MockFile) Stat() (os.FileInfo, error) {
    return MockFileInfo{mf}
}

func OpenMockFile(data []byte) *MockFile {
    mf := MockFile{data, true, 0}
}
```

Comment: admittedly I'm not sure if `MockFile.Stat()` quite lives up to its expectation. It could be that `MockFileInfo` should take a `MockFile` rather than a `*MockFile`. What happens if you `os.Stat` a real file, then change its size? Does the file size change reflect in the `os.FileInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking this answer to gzip http2 push, you can do it with just options:

```
options := &http.PushOptions{
                Header: http.Header{
                    "Accept-Encoding": r.Header["Accept-Encoding"],
                },
            }
            if err := pusher.Push(filePush, options); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Failed to push: %v", err)
                return
            }
```